# Odd Serial behavior with Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I'm not understanding what's going on with my Uno. I have a very simple piece of code. no peripherals are connected. Just a bare genuine uno. I program in VisualMicro for Visual Studio.

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    char stringy[9] = { 0x7E, 0x00, 0x05, 0x08, 0x01, 0x44, 0x33, 0x04, 0x7B };

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        Serial.print(stringy[i]);
        //delay(300);
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("done");
}

void loop()
{
    while (1) {  }
}
```

Without a delay of around 250msec or greater in the for loop, I don't get all the characters. In fact, without the delay, the code doesn't even finish executing. I only get the first character '~'. It doesn't seem to matter what my baud rate is.

This code runs fine without a delay on my Nano. What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: Your program works as expected on my Uno.

Comment: Weird. You get the whole array of gibberish in your serial pane? I'm starting to think its just a difference in compilers.

Comment: Not the serial pane (I'm not using the IDE). I typed `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw 115200 && hd -n 15 /dev/ttyACM0` on the Linux console and got `00000000  7e 00 05 08 01 44 33 04  7b 0d 0a 64 6f 6e 65     |~....D3.{..done|` (`hd` is a hexdump utility).

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the unprintable.

Do you think it should print:

```
~0581,34{
```

or

```
0x7E 0x00 0x05 0x08 0x01 0x44 0x33 0x04 0x7B
```

What you will get is

```
tilde
null
enquiry
backspace
start of heading
comma
three
end of transmission
open brace
```

I think you can call

```
Serial.print(stringy[i], HEX);
```

To see the number you put in come out.

Comment: I expect it to come out gibberish, like this: `~    D3 {`  (three of those white spaces actually show as strange characters that I can't paste here.) The actual content of the array is an Xbee AT command, and I designed this as an experiment to see why it's not working.

See, when I use the Xbee library with the nano and monitor the serial output without the xbee connected, `~    D3 {` is what I see. But on the Uno, all I get out is `~`. In this experiment I was trying to replicate the output with serial.print(), and the result is the same.